# Angular y Mailchimp devuelven error de CORS

Tags: javascript, angular, email, cors

He creado con Angular un formulario que al enviarse conecta con la API de Mailchimp para añadir un nuevo miembro a una lista de suscriptores. El problema es que al realizar la petición me devuelve un error de CORS.

Es la 1a vez que uso Mailchimp con Angular y sigo teniendo el mismo error, he estado investigando pero no doy con la respuesta acertada. Este es el código (simplificado para realizar la pregunta):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MailService {

  private readonly url = `https://US_ID.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/AUDIENCE_ID/members`;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  addEmail(): Observable<any> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer API_KEY`);
        headers = headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    const data = {
      email_address: 'example@gmail.com',
      status: 'subscribed',
      mergeFields: {
        FNAME: 'John',
        LNAME: 'Doe'
      }
    };

    return this.http.post(this.url, data, { headers });
  }

}
```

Espero vuestra ayuda, gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlo desde el backend, en la documentación en español dice:

> Debido a los posibles riesgos de seguridad asociados con la exposición de las claves API de la cuenta, Mailchimp no admite la implementación del lado del cliente de nuestra API mediante solicitudes CORS ni la inclusión de claves API en aplicaciones móviles.

[Acerca de las claves API | Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/es/help/about-api-keys/)

Comment: Muchas gracias René. Lo haré de esa manera.